# strange networking issue with only one of my Ubuntu 22.04 machines

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

my home network is pretty simple. 2 ubuntu 22.04 machines, a windows 11 machine and a WD nas unit.  all are visible in their respective file managers.  what is strange is this:  Linux1 works just fine, it can access the windows shares and the windows machine can access it's shares.  but not so much with linux2.  It can see and access the windows shares just fine.  the windows machine can see the linux2 shares but cannot access them.  I get a message telling me that I don't have permissions to access these files and to contact my network administrator to get them.  The samba conf files are the same, the wsdd files are the same, the users are the same. this is kinda driving me nuts, anyone have any suggestions? oh BTW the permissions on the shared files are setup identically also. there is no server per se just workstations operating in a peer-to-peer fashion ( unless you could consider the nas as a server, i suppose)

Comment: could be a windows issue not a linux issue.  Windows only supports one user per host, and if you're already connected with the wrong user, you can't fix it without disconnecting all shares from that host and reconnecting.

Comment: Other option is that in Linux2 machine the file rights and ownership is not right. Samba shares for Windows are dictated in the end by Linux file ownership (chown command) and rights to file (chmod command). ls -l to see these settings. See https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_File_Serving